# vb.net - Insertion Index was out of range - cause?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, error-handling, visual-studio-2013

I have a weird situation with my program.
While it works fine for most users , a few different users are receiving this error:

[image]

Now please notice the error is not the regular "index was out of range" that's caused by referencing outside of an array or a list - but its a specific "insertion index was out of range".
I've tried to find similar cases by googling without much luck and for the life of me i have no idea why this specific sub causes this exception.

Please remember:

1. This error only shows up for some users while for other users running the same program it works fine.
2. I can't replicate the error on my machine and find the exact line of code that causes it as it works fine on my machine (and on the machines of people close to me , the errors happens on machines in other countries).

I'm thinking this might be a .Net issue i'm not aware of , maybe some users don't have an updated .Net framework installed.

I'd appreciate any ideas on the subjects.

The subroutine that causes the error:
(had to replace some information with X's for obvious reasons)

```
    Private Sub SendRequest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SendRequest.Click

    'Add current data in X to the Request Table sql table.
    Dim ReqQuery As String
    Dim cnReq As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim cmdReq As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim SKUcounter As Integer

    cnReq = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("XXX")

    cmdReq.Connection = cnReq

    'Define SQL Parameters
    With cmdReq
        .Parameters.Add("@X", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 800)
        .Parameters.Add("@X", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 800)
        .Parameters.Add("@X", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 800)
        .Parameters.Add("@X", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 800)
        .Parameters.Add("@X", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 800)
        .Parameters.Add("@X", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 800)
        .Parameters.Add("@X", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 800)
        .Parameters.Add("@X", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 800)
        .Parameters.Add("@X", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 800)
        .Parameters.Add("@X", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 800)
        .Parameters.Add("@X", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 800)
        .Parameters.Add("@X", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 800)
        .Parameters.Add("@X", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 800)
        .Parameters.Add("@X", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 800)
        .Parameters.Add("@X", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 800)
        .Parameters.Add("@X", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 800)
        .Parameters.Add("@X", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 800)
        .Parameters.Add("@X", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 800)
        .Parameters.Add("@X", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 800)
        .Parameters.Add("@X", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 800)
        .Parameters.Add("@X", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 800)
        .Parameters.Add("@X", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 800)
        .Parameters.Add("@X", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 800)
        .Parameters.Add("@X", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 800)
        .Parameters.Add("@X", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 800)
        .Parameters.Add("@X", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 800)
        .Parameters.Add("@X", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 800)
    End With

    Try
        cnReq.Open()
    Catch err As OleDb.OleDbException
        Dim errorMsg As String
        Dim i As Integer
        errorMsg = ""
        For i = 0 To err.Errors.Count - 1
            errorMsg += "Index #" & i.ToString() & ControlChars.Cr _
                           & "Message: " & err.Errors(i).Message & ControlChars.Cr _
                           & "NativeError: " & err.Errors(i).NativeError & ControlChars.Cr _
                           & "Source: " & err.Errors(i).Source & ControlChars.Cr _
                           & "SQLState: " & err.Errors(i).SQLState & ControlChars.Cr
        Next i
    End Try


    'Loop through each row in X and add to sql table
    For SKUcounter = 0 To X.Rows.Count - 2

        ReqQuery = "Insert Into Requests (X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X," _
            & "X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
        cmdReq.CommandText = ReqQuery

        Try
            With cmdReq
                .Parameters("@X").Value = UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName
                .Parameters("@X").Value = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now)
                .Parameters("@X").Value = DGVrequest.Rows(SKUcounter).Cells("SiVersion").Value
                .Parameters("@X").Value = DGVrequest.Rows(SKUcounter).Cells("WiFiIPNCol").Value
                .Parameters("@X").Value = DGVrequest.Rows(SKUcounter).Cells("BTYN").Value
                .Parameters("@X").Value = DGVrequest.Rows(SKUcounter).Cells("VPROYN").Value
                .Parameters("@X").Value = DGVrequest.Rows(SKUcounter).Cells("BTIPTNCol").Value
                .Parameters("@X").Value = DGVrequest.Rows(SKUcounter).Cells("WiGigIPNCol").Value
                .Parameters("@X").Value = DGVrequest.Rows(SKUcounter).Cells("WiGigSSID").Value
                .Parameters("@X").Value = DGVrequest.Rows(SKUcounter).Cells("WiGigDID").Value
                .Parameters("@X").Value = DGVrequest.Rows(SKUcounter).Cells("WiGigNVMTypeCol").Value
                .Parameters("@X").Value = DGVrequest.Rows(SKUcounter).Cells("DueDateCol").Value
                .Parameters("@X").Value = DGVrequest.Rows(SKUcounter).Cells("ProductCode").Value
                .Parameters("@X").Value = DGVrequest.Rows(SKUcounter).Cells("WiGigCode").Value
                .Parameters("@X").Value = DGVrequest.Rows(SKUcounter).Cells("Regulatory").Value
                .Parameters("@X").Value = DGVrequest.Rows(SKUcounter).Cells("HWFF").Value
                .Parameters("@X").Value = DGVrequest.Rows(SKUcounter).Cells("DID").Value
                .Parameters("@X").Value = DGVrequest.Rows(SKUcounter).Cells("WiFiSSID").Value
                .Parameters("@X").Value = "New"
                .Parameters("@X").Value = DGVrequest.Rows(SKUcounter).Cells("OPSCommentsCol").Value
                .Parameters("@X").Value = DGVrequest.Rows(SKUcounter).Cells("ProductYear").Value
                .Parameters("@X").Value = DGVrequest.Rows(SKUcounter).Cells("BUS").Value
                .Parameters("@X").Value = DGVrequest.Rows(SKUcounter).Cells("OEM").Value
                .Parameters("@X").Value = DGVrequest.Rows(SKUcounter).Cells("SAR").Value
                .Parameters("@X").Value = DGVrequest.Rows(SKUcounter).Cells("RegulatorySpecialSettings").Value
                .Parameters("@X").Value = DGVrequest.Rows(SKUcounter).Cells("RequestorEmail").Value
                .Parameters("@X").Value = DGVrequest.Rows(SKUcounter).Cells("BTproductID").Value
            End With

        Catch ex1 As Exception
            MsgBox("Error sendReq - " + vbCrLf + ex1.ToString)
        End Try
        cmdReq.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Next

    'Clear Xfrom data.
    If X.Columns.Contains("StatusQ") Then
        X.Columns.Remove("StatusQ")
    End If
    dtReq.Clear()
    dsReq.Clear()
    X.DataSource = dtReq
    X.DataSource = Nothing
    'Mark flag so "Changes Not Saved" will not appear.
    FirstOpenFlag = True
    'Reload data.
    GetRequestsTableOpen(X.Text)
    MsgBox("Request Sent Successfuly!")

End Sub
```

Comment: How do you know the error is from this subroutine; for example, could it be in `GetRequestsTableOpen()`? The problem is almost certainly in your code somewhere and not in the .NET Framework. Until at the very least you have a stack trace pinpointing the location of the problem, I wouldn't consider blaming the framework.

Comment: First of all , like i said - the code works fine for most users.
Moreover the GetRequestsTableOpen() subroutine is called at least 4 times in other parts of the code and never causes this error.

I know the error is caused by this specific routine as it happens after the click event that this routine handles.

Comment: You use SKUCounter as index in the DataGridView rows, but the loop is on a different variable. It is a typo

Comment: It's only a typo here as i changed it to X in the loop declaration (i didn't want to pose publicly the variable name) and forgot to change the DataGridView also , i'll edit the post to exactly how it shows in the code :)

Comment: I'm not sure if this might be related to your problem, but I don't see `cnReq` being closed or disposed.

Comment: Thanks Michael , i'll update it. Though i still don't think that's where the problem is.

Comment: Is it possible that one of your cells could have more than 800 chars?

Comment: First test i did was having the user send an empty request that the biggest entry in was maybe 30 chars - they still received the error.
Is it possible it might have something to do with time zones? can't possibly think of why but that's the only variable between users that get the error and those who don't.

Comment: Just to be sure ask your user to send you the Stack Trace through the Details button.

Comment: This error message is a resource string located in the `mscorelib` under the name `ArgumentOutOfRange_ArrayListInsert`. It's throw whenever you try to insert an item into an `ArrayList` with an index `< 0` or `> Count`. [Line 477](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/arraylist.cs#477)

Comment: Thing is i don't use any ArrayList here.
Also if this was the issue then the error would happen for ALL users and not just specific ones.

Comment: *Here* as in `the entire application` or as in `the provided code`? For all I know, if not an array list, you might be using an object inheriting it. Your last statement is **incorrect**. You of all (as a programmer) should know that there are **a lot** of things that might (and eventually will) vary from one computer to another. With all due respect, looking at your code, I believe with 99,9% certainty that this is a bug caused by your code and not the API.

Comment: I meant in the provided code. Obviously i'm not an experienced programmer , that's why i'm on this site looking for help. I'd really like you to consider and answer this points if possible: 1) I didn't use inheritance anywhere in my code , this is really a case of what you see is what you get. The user licks on the button and the code above is what happens and only what happens. 2) why would the error show for some users while working fine for other? (for the same data input also)

Comment: Even though *you* don't use an array list there might be objects you're using throughout the application that relies (internally) on an array list. There can be tons of reasons as to why this error occurs. If the code you've provided is a reflection of your average "coding style" then my best guess is as follows. Somewhere down the pipe an error occurs (maybe culture related like date format or decimal/currency separator). The error is **catched** but you **don't exit** the code block (sub/function). The code continuous to execute until it hit's the unhandled exception (ref. picture).

Comment: This might be a red herring, but since you mention that the problem shows in other countries: keep in mind that `String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now)` will format differently in some countries (ie., the separators will use whatever is appropriate for the current culture). It's possible that might confuse something that reads the data later. What countries exhibit the problem?  Try replacing that expression with `"12-31-2001 13.59.21"` and testing on your machine to see if any problems crop up.

Comment: Thanks Michael , i think that's exactly the issue as the column in the sql table is defined as DateTime and throws out an out of bounds exception when i try to input a datetime with a different foramt.
Will look for a solution now.

Comment: Steve - if only users would do what they're told ! working on the stack trace :)

Comment: @Ned: I think that something like this will do the trick: `String.Format( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now)`

Comment: Thanks Michael , think that solved it (really wish i could test it locally!)